# Exclusion in a project dependency does not reflect in other dependent projects in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I have a project A, which excludes a dependency D.

```
   configurations{
    sourceGeneration
    all {
        exclude group: "group-to-be-excluded", module: "module-to-be-excluded"
    }
  }
```

when i do a `gradle dependencies` on project A, as expected, i do not see "group-to-be-excluded" in its dependency chart.

Now, i have a project B, which has a dependency to Project A.

```
    project.dependencies {
        providedCompile "project-A:$version"
    }
```

Now, when i do a `gradle dependencies`, i suddenly start seeing "group-to-be-excluded" listed.

```
\--- project-B:version
     +--- project-A:version
     |    +--- group-to-be-excluded
```

This creates a lot of run time issues for us, where it keeps referring to the older jar from group to be excluded. Is there any way i can ensure that this group does get excluded, without again excluding it in project B code? Appreciate any inputs on the same!

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a [mcve]?

Comment: If the group you are excluding is a transitive dependency, I don't think this method will work. It may need to be added to the `dependencies` configuration of project `A`